# recursion acceleration after 10,000

Tags: c#, recursion, time

i'm running this code:

```
public static void func(int i)
{             
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        func(i + 1);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    func(0);
}
```

obviously it causes StackOverflowException, but something weird happens: From i = 0 to i = 10,000 it runs pretty slow, (about 13 seconds on my computer, using visual studio 2015) but from 10,000 to 20,000 it's almost immediately (about 1 second). Why is why is it happening?

Thanks.

Comment: In debug mode or optimized release?

Comment: How do you measure/observe this?

Comment: Did you define the buffer size of your console window to be 10,000 lines? The WriteLine is the slowest part in your code.

Comment: One second is not "immediate", ~2 billion cpu instructions never are.  Scrolling a console window is not fast but 13 seconds is too long for 10000 lines.  Buffer size has nothing to do with it.  The kind of rock you have look under is stuff like anti-malware, it forever gets its a wedgie when an EXE appears from nowhere.  Disable it and try again.  But do move on, nothing to see here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the buffer size of your console window to be 10,000 lines? The `WriteLine` is the slowest part in your code. The console window seems to be faster once it reached the maximum number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something about the Visual Studio configuration or something specific to your machine. When I run your code in release config it gets executed within 3 milliseconds. In debug mode the "i" never passes 9000 ...

```
class Program
    {
        public static void func(int i)
        {
            if (i % 1000 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:ff") + " => i : " + i.ToString());
            func(i + 1);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            func(0);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: That's because you avoided the most expensive part of the code - the frequent `Console.WriteLine`. As for the lower recursion amount, I'd guess "64-bit" - the stack size is still the same, but each `push` means 64-bit instead of 32-bit. That's just a wild guess, though - there's plenty of other things that can be affecting this.

Comment: Yes Luaan, you are right! adding that its a machine running in core-i-5 and other "not bad" parts :D

Answer (score 0):

I ran this piece of code in tutorialspoint's online c# compiler:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    static TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("Result.txt");

    public static void func(int i)
    {

        if (i > 40000)
            return;

        tw.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " " + i);
        tw.Flush();
        func(i + 1);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        stopwatch.Start();
        func(0);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        tw.Close();
    }
}
```

The result I got is the [this](http://pastebin.com/29H9Dz8Y)

As you can see there are a few jumps in the time, specifically at 20461 and 20548. I don't know what to make of this though...